# Unable to get JSON response from URLConnection

Tags: java, json, httprequest, urlconnection

I am trying to read a response from googleapi using java URLConnection.

In browser if i query 
"https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zauq.se&strategy=mobilez"

i gets response in JSON formate.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidParameter",
    "message": "Invalid string value: 'mobilez'. Allowed values: [desktop, mobile]",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "strategy"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid string value: 'mobilez'. Allowed values: [desktop, mobile]"
 }
}
```

But when i use following code.

```
URL url = null;
            System.setProperty("http.agent", "");

            url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zauq.se&strategy=mobilez");//"https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=" + paramUrl + "&strategy=" + paramStrategy);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String strTemp = "";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((null != (strTemp = br.readLine())))
            {
                sb.append(strTemp);
                if (dump)
                {
                    System.out.println(strTemp);
                }
            }
```

i get IO Exception

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zauq.se&strategy=mobilez
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1627)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at amirTest.PageSpeedCheck.main(PageSpeedCheck.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

/ but i need to get JSON response.

Please suggest me the change need to make to get the JSON as a response.

Comment: "Invalid string value: 'mobilez'. Allowed values: [desktop, mobile]" : Message is clear enough

Comment: You are sending mobilez instead of mobile i guess. check my answer below

Comment: Please add to the question, that an error is what you want as result, but that the format should be JSON. Otherwise people try to help you trying a HTTP/200 with a URL that does not allow ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Cast the connection to a Http(s)URLConnection, and call [getErrorStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream--) to get the stream in case of error.

Comment: Thanks , it worked.


 InputStream is = null;
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == 400)
            {

                is = conn.getErrorStream();
                error = true;
            } else
            {
                is = conn.getInputStream();
            }

Answer (score 1):

**For : 400** :-

You are sending strategy as *mobile**z*** instead of *mobile*

Change

https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zauq.se&strategy=mobilez

to

https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zauq.se&strategy=mobile

notice the z at the end of your URL

**To grab JSON response :**

Refer : [How to Parse this JSON Response in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18899232/3603806)

Comment: i know its wrong, means i wanted to get error message . but that error message should be like the one we get in browser, JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters used in your API call is wrong hence the server is retunrning status code 400. Which means it is a BAD request.

mobilz should be mobile. Also the url which your are using is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, the sample host is wrong, shows when using correct molie parameter.

Comment: i know its wrong, means i wanted to get error message . but that error message should be like the one we get in browser, JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change you code as below:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(((HttpURLConnection) (new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zauq.se&strategy=mobilez")).openConnection())
.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

See original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9350031/2949612)

See similar SO questions as below:

[URLConnection Error - java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931164/urlconnection-error-java-io-ioexception-server-returned-http-response-code-4)

[Server returned HTTP response code: 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349703/server-returned-http-response-code-400)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ JB Nizet

It worked as i tried reading Error Stream.

```
            InputStream is = null;
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == 400)
            {

                is = conn.getErrorStream();
                error = true;
            } else
            {
                is = conn.getInputStream();
            }
```